# PHP Login redirect to template pages pulling in different user data

Tags: php, authentication

I have created a login account for my website and i need to be able to direct users to different pages. I've generated the php login from Dreamweaver so there maybe extra code. I've tried adding a switch session but this makes the page not load... please help gurus...

The login page is client.php and the redirect page is client_info.php

Here is the client.php code (with better formatting):

```
<?php require_once('Connections/fhvps_db.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue         
    = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?     
    mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;    
case "long":
case "int":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "double":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
  break;
case "date":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
  break;
case "defined":
  $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
  break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}
?>


<?php
// *** Validate request to login to this site.
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
session_start();
}

$loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
  $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
}

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
  $password=$_POST['password'];
  $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "client_info.php";
  $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "home.php";
  $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
  mysql_select_db($database_fhvps_db, $fhvps_db);

  $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT username, password FROM `user` WHERE username=%s AND     
    password=%s",
    GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

  $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $fhvps_db) or die(mysql_error());
  $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
  if ($loginFoundUser) {
 $loginStrGroup = "";

if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
//declare two session variables and assign them
$_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
$_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
  $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
}
header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
  }
  else {
header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
  }
}



?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title></title>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<link href="css/fh.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</style>
<style type="text/css">
body {
background-color: #;
background-color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<img class="bgimage" src="images/bg/bg_login.png" />
<div id="wrapperheader">

<?php 
include 'header.php';
?>
</div>
<div id="layout">
<div id="main">
<div id="login">
  <h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CLIENT LOGIN</h2><br/>
  <form ACTION="<?php echo $loginFormAction; ?>" name="loginForm" method="POST">
  <fieldset id="loginFieldset">
<p>
            <label for="username">User Name:</label>

            <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="15" maxlength="10" />
            <br />
            <br/>       
      <label for="password">Password:</label>

  <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="15" maxlength="10" />
  <br />
  <br/>
    <p><input type="submit" id="sendButton" value="Login" class="sendButton" />
      <br />
    </p>
</fieldset>
</form><br /><br />


</div>




</div>
</div>
<div id="wrapperfooter">
<?php 
include 'footer.php';
?>



    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is returning a value: `return $theValue;` before you're sending the redirect header.

Make sure you send the redirect header before you return.